# how to best copy a union whose largest member is unknown

Tags: c

Here is a structure in C, it contains one of several types of data, and we don't know which data is has the largest `sizeof`:

```
typedef
    struct {
        union {
            void *p_data;
            size_t s_data;
        };
        int extra_stuff;
    }
    data_and_stuff;
```

Now I want the most efficient way to copy (any) data from one instance of the structure to another, like so:

```
void copy_data(data_and_stuff *from, data_and_stuff *to) 
{
    to->p_data = from->p_data ;  \\ WRONG!
}
```

Of course, this is wrong, since maybe `sizeof(size_t) > sizeof(void *)`.

Using preprocessor to define the largest member name, does not work, since I can't use `sizeof()` there.

OK, I could give the union a name, yes (as commenters suggested) but I don't want to, because, this name will then be used in all sorts of code, it will make all code harder to understand.

So here's what I came up with, kind of ugly:

```
typedef
    struct {
        union {
            void *p_data;
            size_t s_data;
            union { void * p; size_t s; } largest_data;
        };
        int extra_stuff;
    }
    data_and_stuff;

void copy_data(data_and_stuff *from, data_and_stuff *to) 
{
    to->largest_data = from->largest_data ;
}
```

Is there a better way?

EDIT: I guess, as John commented, my code is not guaranteed by the standard to work :) .  I mean it "should", but, the standard explicitly says, to not read one member of the union, after writing to another.

Comment: Can you give the anonymous union a name?

Comment: @dbush well I don't really want to, I don't need it otherwise and it will complicate dereferencing.  Let's say I don't want to unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: yes so the question should be, I want to avoid a name, because it will be used in other cases explicitly and so it will complicate the interface unnecessarily

Comment: Since unions are kind of magical, you either need to have something that knows about the union type to copy, or you need to memcpy the entire union, which would therefore have to be named.

Comment: @dbush thank you, I guess that is it then

Comment: There are at most `offsetof(data_and_stuff, extra_stuff)` bytes in the union, so `memcpy(to, from, offsetof(data_and_stuff, extra_stuff))` will copy them, possibly along with some padding bytes.

Comment: "the standard explicitly says, to not read one member of the union, after writing to another."  No it doesn't. That's the C++ standard, not the C standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is a structure in C, it contains one of several types of data, and we don't know which data is has the largest `sizeof`

It's not a question of knowing which union member has the largest size.  You need to copy the member, if any, that actually has a value stored in it, or else the whole union (which you cannot do because it is anonymous), or else the whole structure.

If you don't know which union member has a value stored, then copying the whole structure is your only valid option.  Thankfully, that's very easy to express ...

```
void copy_data(data_and_stuff *from, data_and_stuff *to) {
    *to = *from;
}
```

... and the compiler is likely to produce code that handles that pretty efficiently.

Comment: OK, but, are you sure what I have above does not work??  All members of union are guaranteed to align on the start of the whole union. So what I have is like `memcpy` but without using addresses.

Comment: @MarkGaleck, I am sure that the code presented in the question has undefined behavior when the member of `*from`'s anonymous union that has a value stored in it is not `largest_data`.  That is not necessarily the same as "does not work" (c.f. "undefined"), but it definitely implies "should not use".

Comment: you mean, the reason why this is undefined, is because the standard has this notion of "active" member,  says, to not read one member of the union, after writing to another  ??

Comment: @MarkGaleck, The strict aliasing rule (paragraph 6.5/7 of the language spec) forbids most variations on accessing an object via a type different from its effective type, which is what I claim you are contemplating here.  I guess there could be an argument that the union hiding under the covers solves that, but I don't read the spec that way.  If you care about portability and robustness then it would be unwise to hang your hat on a more permissive interpretation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger As far as strict aliasing is concerned, you can "lvalue access" the contents of a union by using any type present in that union.  C is more tolerant than C++ here.

Comment: Specifically 6.5/7 "An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue expression that has one of the following types: - a type compatible with the effective type of the object, /--/ - an aggregate or union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its members (including, recursively, a member of a subaggregate or contained union)"

Comment: Regarding union type punning see 6.5.2.3/3, or more helpfully the informative foot note: "If the member used to read the contents of a union object is not the same as the member last used to store a value in the object, the appropriate part of the object representation of the value is reinterpreted as an object representation in the new
type as described in 6.2.6 (a process sometimes called “type punning”). This might be a trap representation."

Comment: @Lundin, you can perform the lvalue-access *via the union* (in C).  It is not at all clear that that should be taken to apply in this case.  Moreover, even if it did apply, and even if you rely on your compiler to recognize that, there is the potential for issues with, e.g., trap representations.

Comment: This is a muddy part of the standard, but as far as I know there may be multiple effective types. 6.2.6.1 "Where an operator is applied to a value that has more than one object representation,
which object representation is used shall not affect the value of the result. Where a
value is stored in an object using a type that has more than one object representation for
that value, it is unspecified which representation is used, but a trap representation shall
not be generated."

Comment: With a foot note: "It is possible for objects x and y with the same effective type T to have the same value when they are accessed as objects of type T, but to have different values in other contexts."

Comment: @Lundin, multiple representations of the same type is different from multiple effective types, and thus irrelevant to the present question.  I do accept that an object can have multiple effective types, but the only place I see that coming into play is with containment.  For example, if `struct example { int i; }` is laid out without padding, then the memory that an instance occupies can be regarded as having both `struct example` and `int` as an effective type, depending on how it is accessed.

Comment: I do not see multiple effective types for the same object at the same time arising from different members of a union, in part because the standard expressly specifies that at most one member of a union contains a value at any given time.